# Serving ML model in production. Tensorflow-serving and autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, architecture, autoscaling, tensorflow-serving

I've been serving an image classification ML model over HTTP.
Running Web server and model as single container unit.
I did not use tensorflow-serving.
Architecture is like this:
[serving without tensorflow-serving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN4Kp.png)

Our kubernetes can autoscales up with workload.
It feels simple, as we develop our model in Python, just add Flask, and we're ready to deploy.
We do not have the added process of converting the model into .PB format required for tensorflow-serving, then deploy two different components (web server, and tensorflow-serving container).

My question is: what would be some of advantages of bringing tensorflow-serving into the picture.
All tutorials out there seems to go with this architecture.
[serving with tensorflow-serving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdPtG.png)

My apology for having images as link, this is my first post here.
Thank you.

Comment: tensorflow-serving itself is a web server. The only reason why you would place a further webserver in front of it is if you want to handle some kind of preprocessing server-side, rather than getting the client to do it. But basically using the approach with the second picture is far more efficient since you are only passing data once. Also TF Serving already handles mutlithreading, batching, queueing etc. out of the box. If you put a Flask app in front of it you need to also build this functionality yourself

Comment: Hi Karl, Thank you for your input.
Even with client side processing, I'd still need a webserver to handle things like authentication, and logging.
And if Flask is not quite for production, we use Gunicorn or Uvicorn.

Comment: Since serving is based on a micro-services architecture , TensorFlow serving will segregate models from the business logic code in web services and make it easier to version/update/serve models without impacting the part where business logic is implemented.

Comment: @krissdap I have a question about the web server you put in front of TF Server. I understand that users must authenticate to access your Flask API but how do you manage the fact that users can directly access TFS api and then skip authentication?